# How do I make a method running subprocess command, asynchronous?

Tags: django, asynchronous, django-rest-framework, redis, celery

**Problem**:

- Using Celery and Redis to make a `subprocess` call asynchronous, which is not working as expected.
- Django Function-based View is making a call to the function which runs the `subprocess` command, and the API request is waiting for the `subprocess` command to complete to return the response.

The below method is called through an function-based views in django. I have made this method a `shared_task` of 'celery' and the message broker used is 'Redis'.

```
import subprocess
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def run_docker_command(command):
    try:
        process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        output, error = process.communicate()
        print("Executed!!")
        if process.returncode == 0:
            print("Command executed successfully.")
            if output:
                print("Output:\n", output.decode())
            return 1
        else:
            print("Command execution failed.")
            if error:
                print("Error:\n", error.decode())
            return 0

    except OSError as e:
        print("Error executing the command:", str(e))
```

When the below endpoint is called (with both django and celery server running), the endpoint `start_container` is waiting until the process inside the `run_docker_command` is completed to give the response.

```
@csrf_exempt
def start_container1(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        from Visiotwin_Configuration.tasks import run_docker_command
        command = "az container start -n <container-name> -g <res-group-name>"
        try:
            task = run_docker_command.apply_async(args=[command])
            print(task)
            res = task.get()
            if res == 1:
                status = "Docker started successfully"
            else:
                status = "Docker failed to start"
        except:
            status = "Something went wrong!"

        return JsonResponse(status, safe=False)
```

Hope the problem statement is clear.

Any suggestions and changes are open.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AsyncResult.get() waits for the task till it's completed and returns the response. If you want your API to return immediately, remove .get() and the status will always be pending.

```
@csrf_exempt
def start_container1(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        from Visiotwin_Configuration.tasks import run_docker_command
        command = "az container start -n <container-name> -g <res-group-name>"
        task = run_docker_command.apply_async(args=[command])

        return JsonResponse(task.status, safe=False)
```